# Generating a 2 digit integer

Tags: java, random

I need to generate a random 2 digit number which will be concatenated to the end of a string. The number MUST be 2 digits (i.e. 00-99, nothing <10 is acceptable).

How can this be done using Java libraries in the simplest way possible?

Comment: You probably mean "i.e. 10-99"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range. Input 10 and 99 as the min and max.

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 0));`

Comment: public class MainClass {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        
               //The String
               String string ="66";
  
               //Generating Two digits Number that is > 10.
               Random r = new Random();
               int randomNum = r.nextInt(99 - 10) + 10;

               //Printing the Concatenated Result
               System.out.println(string+"-"+randomNum);

            }

            }

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way would be to generate two random integers separately, and then add them to the end of your string. That way anything from 1-9 would show up as 01-09.

Using this answer, [Generating random integers in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range), you generate the two integers. Then create an empty string and add the two variables you used to store your random integers.

Psuedocode:

```
int a = RANDOMNUMBER
int b = RANDOMNUMBER
String number = "" + a + b
```

Comment: Or just use the random method with a range of 10-99

Comment: Can you suggest how I would do this? :)

Comment: I'm assuming that you actually want values between 0 and 9, just represented in two digits. I added the pseudocode, you should have enough to solve your issue

Comment: /*For range 10-99*/
Random rand = new Random();
int num = rand.nextInt(99 - 10 + 1) + 10;